# (React) Should I first check the state-variable before I call setState?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I have a code-function running all 4 Seconds (timer).
This timer sets a variable. Let`s say:

```
this.setState({
    VariableA: false
});
```

Now this code runs all 4 seconds. Most of the time the VariableA is false. So should I first check if the variable is false or does react check if the variable is false?
For better understanding, should I write Code-A or Code-B:

**Code-A:**

```
function doSomething(){
        this.setState({
            VariableA: false
        }); 
}
```

**Code-B:**

```
function doSomething(){
     if(this.state.VariableA != false){
        this.setState({
            VariableA: false
        }); 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` causes a re-render which is essentially leads to `reconcilation` of your DOM, now even though nothing has changed a reconcilation phase will occur, you could avoid it by using `PureComponent` which basically implements a shallow comparison in `shouldComponentUpdate` and doesn't trigger a re-render if nothing changed in state or props and it can handle a lot more cases rather than you comparing the state each and everytime before `setState`

According to the **[documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent)**:

> `React.PureComponent` implements it with a shallow prop and state
>   comparison. If your React component’s `render()` function renders the
>   same result given the same props and state, you can use
>   `React.PureComponent` for a performance boost in some cases

Comment: True as Shubham said!

Answer (score 0):

Before running re-render, React will check if state has changed. I guess, if you have more complex state, that you should make check yourself, since React will run checks on all of the state properties.